# Activate second worksheet with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to activate multiple excel worksheets and write to both multiple sheets within both workbook(s) using python and openpyxl. I am able to load the second workbook `f` but I am unable to append cell G2 of my second workbook with the string `Recon`

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

filename = 'sda_2015.xlsx'

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws['G1'] = 'Path'
ws.title = 'Main'

adf = "Dirty Securities 04222015.xlsx"
f = "F:\\ana\\xlmacro\\" + adf

wb2 = load_workbook(f)
"""
wb22 = Workbook(wb2)
ws = wb22.active

ws['G1'] = "Recon2"
ws.title = 'Main2'
"""
print wb2.get_sheet_names()

wb.save(filename)
```

I commented out the code which is broken

**Update**
I adjusted my code with the below answer. The value in cell `H1` is written onto `wb2` in column H, but for some reason the column is hidden. I have adjusted the column to other columns but still I have seen the code hide multiple columns. There are also occurences when the code executes and titles `ws2` as `Main21` but the encoded value is `Main2`

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

filename = 'sda_2015.xlsx'

wb1 = Workbook()
ws1 = wb1.active

ws1['G1'] = 'Path'
ws1.title = 'Main'

adf = "Dirty Securities 04222015.xlsx"
f = "F:\\ana\\xlmacro\\" + adf

wb2 = load_workbook(f)

ws2 = wb2.active

ws2['H1'] = 'Recon2'
ws2.title = 'Main2'

print wb2.get_sheet_names()

wb1.save(filename)
wb2.save(f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had experienced the same thing with hidden cells.  Eventually, I unpacked the Excel file and looked at the raw XML to find out that not all of the columns had a dimension for width.  Those without a width were being by Excel.

A quick fix is to do something like this...

```
for col in 'ABCDEFG':
    if not worksheet.column_dimensions[col].width:
        worksheet.column_dimensions[col].width = 10
```

Comment: I don't see the relation to the original question and in any case if the width is missing for column_dimension then the default is applied.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two workbooks open, wb1 and wb2, you'll also need different names for the various worksheets: `ws1 = wb1.active` and `ws2 = wb2.active`.

If you're working with a file with macros, you'll need to set the `keep_vba` flag to `True` when opening it in order to preserve the macros.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the question. The mailing list probably makes more sense.

Comment: mailing list?? Please copy and paste the update code from above and execute (replacing with a excel workbook on your comp) and let me please know if, once the code is executed, whether you see the value `Recon2` on workbook 2 ? Every time I run the code I see the value but for some reason Column H is hidden

Comment: Without the files I cannot expect to replicate the behaviour. You can check a column's hidden status with `ws.column_dimensions['H']``

The mailing list is linked to from the documentation.